Wordpress theme didnt show menu
I'm new to using WordPress, so I want to use an existing theme, but when I use the theme there is only one menu, namely the sample page and no other menus, how do I fix it?
I hope someone knows how to fix it,please help me

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Which theme?
Maybe the theme only supports one menu
